# BreezeJS Predicates on 2nd level expanded entities

Tags: breeze

A similar question has been asked on this matter:
[Breeze work-around for multi valued property queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752972/breeze-work-around-for-multi-valued-property-queries)

Well, that works for one-one-many.
i.e parent entity may have one child which in turn has many children.

My scenario is : A product has many units, a particular unit has many barcodes.

```
var predicateBarcode = Predicate.create('units.barcodes','any','barcode', 'eq', searchText());

 var query = EntityQuery.from('Products')
             .expand('units.barcodes')
             // .take(10)
             .where(predicateBarcode );
            return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);
```

Executing the Query gives an error:

```
The parent value for a property access of a property 'barcodes' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.
```

I've changed the predicate to:

```
var predicateBarcode = Predicate.create('units','any','barcodes','any','barcode', 'eq', searchText());
```

which gives another error:

```
The Any/All nesting limit of '1' has been exceeded. 'MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth' can be configured on ODataQuerySettings or QueryableAttribute
```

Is there any way around this?
Help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775107/breeze-predicate-on-multiple-levels-of-children/21779728#21779728

Comment: You can also be interested by that one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635376/how-to-apply-maxexpansiondepth-globally-or-to-an-entire-controller-in-breeze/21706389#21706389

Comment: Thanks @lnu. changed the MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth property in my controller and it worked. I voted up for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the predicate:

```
var predicateBarcode = Predicate.create('units','any','barcodes','any','barcode', 'eq', searchText());
```

I have added the `MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth`property to my breeze controller :

```
[BreezeController(MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 2)]
```

Thanks to @lnu..

Comment: I just ran into this error myself.  I am able to set MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth for the BreezeController attribute (I mean the compiler didn't complain), but it didn't eliminate the error.  Maybe that is a bug ... not sure.  But I will say that when I moved the value to the EnableBreezeQuery attribute the error did go away.