# Breeze where query for many-to-many with intermediate entity in EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

I am using EF6, WebApi2, AngularJS and BreezeJs.

I have the following entities:

```
Person
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<GenericProfileCountry> Countries { get; protected set; }
}

public class GenericProfileCountry
{
    public string PersonId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person{ get; set; }
    public string CountryIso { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public string Iso { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a query that brings all Persons through breeze as follows:

```
return zEntityQuery.from('Contacts').expand('Profile, Countries')
        .orderBy(contactOrderBy)
        .toType(entityName)
        .using(self.manager).execute()
        .to$q(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);
```

What I would like to do is perform a where statement on the above query with criteria that are on the intermediate entity. So say I want to bring only contacts that their first country (a person can have multiple countries) iso code is equal to 'GB'.

In Linq it would be something like Contacts.Where(contact => contact.Countries.First().CountryIso == 'GB')

Could something similar be expressed in the where(predicate) of breeze? I thought of going the other way (start from the intermediate table and filter from there), but not sure if that is the correct approach.

Comment: If someone knows how to do the same for the Select command of breeze (ie select Projection instead of full entity) it would be great to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a predicate with the keyword `any` or `all`

```
.where('Countries','any','CountryIso','eq','GB')
```

In case you want to create a predicate on grand children : [BreezeJS Predicates on 2nd level expanded entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970720/breezejs-predicates-on-2nd-level-expanded-entities/21973810#21973810)

**Edit**

If you want to get the **first** contacts whose countries Isos start with 'GB', you can achieve that by:

1. Jay's suggestion.
2. using Linq at Breeze controller:

   ```
   public IQueryable<Person> ContactsWithFilteredCountryIso(string CountryIso)
       {
           return _contextProvider.Context.Persons.Where(p => p.Countries.First().CountryIso== CountryIso);
        }
   ```

Then on the client:

```
return zEntityQuery.from('Contacts')
        .withParameters({ CountryIso: "GB"})
        .expand('Profile, Countries')
        .orderBy(contactOrderBy)
        .toType(entityName)
        .using(self.manager).execute()
        .to$q(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);
```

Comment: What about taking the first item in the countries collection instead of any?

Comment: I can't think of any way unless you have some property on a country instance itself that indicates that it is first. Then you could add to the subquery an expression like 'and("SeqNum", "eq", 1)'

Comment: @JayTraband That's exactly what I wanted to say. Another way, he can do it with Linq as a webMethod if he wants to get the first in each collection

Comment: @AdelSal can you please elaborate on that? Also although not in the original question, what would be the way to select that CountryIso using the .select method of breeze?

Comment: @mxa055 elaborate on what Jay suggested? or the Web Method? Why do you want to select CountryIso when using a condition on the same field? all values will be the same which in this case 'GB'.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the comment in a hurry and didn't really think it through before hitting enter. I did not get the part about the WebMethod actually, so I would like some info on that. As for the select it is not the CountryIso field I would want as you are correct in saying this is the filter but rather the Country.Iso and Country.Name of the table record pointed by CountryIso (Country.Iso would be the same in this example, but I think you get what I mean) The question is how would you write a select for a many to one relations say Countries.Country.Name or sth

Comment: @mxa055 Sorry for the late response. I have updated the unswer

Comment: @mxa055 As for selecting fields from children, you can do the same with Linq. At the client side, I'm not sure how to achieve that, since I don't usually limit myself to selecting particular fields as I can bind whatever field I want with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a select projection on countries with bringing up Contacts can be implemented by issuing a Breeze query on countries and expanding contact:

```
return zEntityQuery.from('Countries').expand('Contact')
        .select('Country.name')
        .where('CountryIso','eq','GB')
        .orderBy(contactOrderBy)
        .toType(entityName)
        .using(self.manager).execute()
        .to$q(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);
```